# Multiple renders to single texture without blocking MTLCommandBuffer

Tags: objective-c, macos, metal, render-to-texture

I am trying to render 3 separate things to one texture in Metal.
I have a MTLTexture that is used as a destination in 3 different MTLCommandBuffers. I commit them one after another. Each MTLCommandBuffer renders to a separate part of the texture - first draws in the 0 - 1/3 part, second draws the middle 1/3 - 2/3 and the last one draws 2/3 - 1.

```
id<MTLTexture> dst_texture = ...;
id<MTLCommandBuffer> buffer1 = [self drawToTexture:dst_texture];
[buffer1 commit];
id<MTLCommandBuffer> buffer2 = [self drawToTexture:dst_texture];
[buffer2 commit];
id<MTLCommandBuffer> buffer3 = [self drawToTexture:dst_texture];
[buffer3 commit];
```

The problem is that it seems I can't *share* the destination texture in the different command buffers - I get glitches, sometimes I can see only partial results on the destination texture...
Inside `drawToTexture` I use dst_texture this way:

```
_renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = dst_texture;
_renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = MTLLoadActionLoad;
```

The problem gets fixed when I call `[buffer waitUntilCompleted]` after each individual commit but I suppose it affects the performance and I would love to have it without blocking/waiting.

This works:

```
id<MTLTexture> dst_texture = ...;
id<MTLCommandBuffer> buffer1 = [self drawToTexture:dst_texture];
[buffer1 commit];
[buffer1 waitUntilCompleted];
id<MTLCommandBuffer> buffer2 = [self drawToTexture:dst_texture];
[buffer2 commit];
[buffer2 waitUntilCompleted];
id<MTLCommandBuffer> buffer3 = [self drawToTexture:dst_texture];
[buffer3 commit];
[buffer3 waitUntilCompleted];
```

What else I could do here to avoid `waitUntilCompleted` calls?

Comment: Are you using the same `MTLCommandQueue` to create the command buffers?

Comment: @FrankSchlegel - yes, the same one for all 3 command buffers

Comment: is there any reason why you are using separate command buffers? Can you not use  one command buffer and 3 encoders or one encoder and 3 draw calls on it.. not sure what drawToTexture does but sounds like it could just be a draw call so you'd only need one command buffer and one encoder..

Comment: @Gary maybe that's something I should look into. What I am doing is I render the same geometry with the same shaders but with a different set of uniforms for each command buffer.

Comment: In that case you should definitely use one command buffer and one encoder, so from the commandBuffer create your renderPassDescriptor attach your texture, create your encoder encode the first draw (set buffers do the draw call), then don't call endEncoding, reset the uniform buffers then draw again, and again and then endEncoding. Then everything will behave as you expect to, this is the standard way of drawing to one texture multiple times.

Comment: @Gary that makes perfect sense! Thanks!

Comment: Are you using textures with untracked hazard tracking mode?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the questions "I am trying to render 3 separate things in one texture in metal", and "What else I could do here to avoid waitUntilCompleted calls?" (Hamid has already explained why the problem occurs), is that you shouldn't be using multiple command buffers for basic rendering with multiple draw calls. If you're rendering to one texture then you need one command buffer which you use to create one renderPassDescriptor that you attach the texture to. Then you need one encoder created from the renderPassDescriptor where you can encode all the draw calls and change of buffers states etc..so as I said in the comment you bind the shader set buffers etc then draw and then don't call endEncoding but set shaders and buffers again and again for how many draw calls and buffer changes you want.
If you wanted to draw to multiple textures then you typically create multiple renderPassDescriptors (but still use one command buffer). Generally you use one command buffer per frame, or for a set of offscreen render passes.

Answer (score 0):

The manual synchronization is only required:

- For Untracked Resources.
- Across Multiple Devices.
- Between a GPU and the CPU.
- Between separate command queues.

otherwise, metal automatically synchronizes resources (tracked) between the command buffers even if they are running in parallel.

If a command buffer includes write or read operations on a given `MTLTexture`, you must ensure that these operations complete before reading or writing the `MTLTexture` contents. You can use the `addCompletedHandler:` method, `waitUntilCompleted` method, or custom semaphores to signal that a command buffer has completed execution.

Comment: Given what he is trying to do "I am trying to render 3 separate things to one texture in Metal", he shouldn't use multiple command buffers but instead use one command buffer and one renderPassDescriptor and one encoder, using waitUntilCompleted or semaphores to ensure execution, while possible is ridiculous for his needs.

Comment: I agree. I was clarifying why the issue occurs in the first place.

Comment: Sure, but I think it's important that the user understands how tools are meant to be used, if he thinks he needs a separate command buffer for every draw call, that severely limits his options and sets him off on the wrong track.